# DataContract not using Name property specified in attribute

Tags: c#, serialization, rest, xml-serialization, wcf

I don't know what serializer is being used but I'm seeing some inconsistent behavior during serialization when using the Name property of the datacontract attribute.

Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ASerCollection")]
public class SerCollection : List<ColElem>
{
}

[DataContract(Name = "SomethignElse", Namespace = "")]
public class ColElem
{

}
```

The problem I'm having is that the serialization is generating something like the following XML:

```
<ASerCollection>
<ColElem />
</ASerCollection>
```

I'm doing this as part of a WCF Service.  Please let me know if there's something I can do differently to force the use of the "Name" attribute of my datacontract.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because:

- XMLRootAttribute is used by XmlSerializer
- DataContractAttribute is used by DataContractSerializer

One does not understand attributes of the other.
Depending on what you are trying to do and the relationships between your classes, I think you should read on how to guide the above mentioned serializers and choose the one that suites the needs.

Here is a couple of links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e123c76w.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd1dc9w5.aspx

Hope this helps a bit.